# Trying to animate and element while scrolling

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a logo scroll to the right and eventually be animated into a hamburger icon. Here is roughly my final goal but done as the page loads rather than scrolls. https://codepen.io/mthauv/pen/gxJNWq

I started by trying to get the logo to go to its right position. The problem I'm having is that it only works if you scroll carefully. If you scroll too fast it either goes too far or not far enough depending on the line...

```
 if( target - mContainer.getBoundingClientRect().right > 0 || startLine - startLine * scrollY/240 > 16 ){
   mContainer.style.right = startLine - startLine * scrollY/240 + "px";
   check = mContainer.style.right.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');   
 }
```

Or statement allows it to scroll too far where an and statement allows it to stop short. I've tried a few other statements but most prevent the logo from returning when scrolling back down.

Here's the pen https://codepen.io/mthauv/pen/aygNbe

HTML

```
 <body>

  <div id="logo-container" class="first-step">
   <div id="m-container" onclick="toggleMenu('menu-btn')">
    <div id="m-1" class="m"></div>
    <div id="m-2" class="m"></div>
    <div id="m-3" class="m"></div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div id="menu-container">
   <ul id="menu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
   </ul>
 </div>

 <div id="content-container" onclick="toggleMenu('body')">
   <h1>Content</h1>
 </div>

</body>
```

And JS

```
var logoContainer = document.getElementById('logo-container');
var mContainer = document.getElementById('m-container');
var menuContainer = document.getElementById('menu-container');
var contentContainer = document.getElementById('content-container');
var m = document.getElementsByClassName('m');

var w = window.innerWidth;
var check = mContainer.style.right.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
var startLine = w/2 - 90;
var totalDistance = window.innerWidth/2;
var target = window.innerWidth - 16;

mContainer.style.right = w/2 - 90 + "px"

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  mContainer.style.right = w/2 - 90 + "px"
  check = mContainer.style.right.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');
  startLine = w/2 - 90;
  totalDistance = w/2;
  target = w - 16;
});

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
  var scrollY = (window.pageYOffset) ;
  var x = scrollY/240;

  if( target - mContainer.getBoundingClientRect().right > 0 || startLine - startLine * scrollY/240 > 16 )
    {
      mContainer.style.right = startLine - startLine * scrollY/240 + "px";
      check = mContainer.style.right.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, '');   
    } 

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
const mContainer = document.getElementById("m-container");

const scrollFinishPosition = 300; // when animation should be finished
const step = scrollFinishPosition / 100;

let startPosition;
let endPosition;
let difference;

function calcSize() {
  const logoWidth = mContainer.offsetWidth; // get width of the logo

  startPosition = window.innerWidth / 2 - logoWidth / 2; // center

  const margin = 80;
  endPosition = window.innerWidth - logoWidth - margin; 

  // used for some simple math later 
  difference = endPosition - startPosition; 
}

function positionLogo() {
  let percentageValue;

  // if scroll position is in animation range - calc % otherwise just use 100%
  if (window.pageYOffset < scrollFinishPosition) {
    percentageValue = pageYOffset / step;
  } else {
    percentageValue = 100;
  }

  // convert % to px and add update styles
  const position = startPosition + difference / 100 * percentageValue;
  mContainer.style.left = position + "px";
}

window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
  calcSize();
  positionLogo()
});

window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  positionLogo();
});

calcSize();
positionLogo();
```

https://codepen.io/Gibala/pen/gxNJRR

Comment: This works and is so much more elegant than what I had. Plus it addresses the issue (which I hadn't found yet) of the window resizing after some scrolling. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this updated pen, I set the position of the M child to absolute, and the parent to fixed so it can move around freely.

I added the below code which checks if the container's right is going off the screen, if so, anchor it instead of continuing.

```
  if (parseFloat(mContainer.style.right) <= 0) {
    mContainer.style.right = '0px';
  }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjKoNE

Comment: That works! Thanks. I had done something similar but I like yours more. I used an else if statement... else if(mContainer.getBoundingClientRect().right/w > 1) {
         mContainer.style.right = '0';
       }